# Selenium: Can't get text from a class element

Tags: java, selenium

I have a html code:

```
    <div class="b7bd16b0909896b5">
        <h3 class="ccd4e6086468523f">PastaMania</h3>
```

This is my code:

```
    List<WebElement> restaurants = 
    driver.findElements(By.className("ccd4e6086468523f"));
            for (WebElement restaurant: restaurants) {
                System.out.println(restaurant.getText());
            }
```

I want to get the text "PastaMania" but I keep getting "placeholder" instead. Anyone know what's wrong?

More of the html code: [outerHTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2NKr.png)

Comment: Both the classes `b7bd16b0909896b5` and `ccd4e6086468523f` looks dynamic to me. Can you update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_?

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for replying, I've updated my question.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

From the information given it's not clear if this className is unique and as @DebanjanB already stated this classname is probably dynamic so it's not a good idea to use this as the locator for your H3 element.

You can use the following code:

```
driver.findElements(By.xPath("//ol/li//h3"));
```

Maybe a little bit of explicit wait, till the h3 element is visible, is needed.

I checked a C# variant and it is giving the correct result. In the final code the Thread.Sleep has to be replaced by a more elegant waiting mechanism.

The results:

```
public void TestDeliveroo()
    {
        Driver.Url = "https://deliveroo.com.sg/restaurants/singapore/chinatown?postcode=069535&preselected_tag=1&tags=guilty+pleasures";
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        IList<IWebElement> restaurants =
            Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ol/li//h3"));
        foreach (var restaurant in restaurants)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(restaurant.Text);
        }
    }
```

Giving this output:

Three Buns at Potato Head Keong Saik
Wine Connection Cheese Bar
Meat Smith
Oven Fried Chicken
Two Blur Guys
Fatboy's The Burger Bar
BERGS
L’Entrecôte The Steak & Fries Bistro
Chir Chir Fusion Chicken Factory - Chinatown Point
Wine Connection Shop@Chinatown Point
Chili's Grill and Bar
Merchants Wine Cellar - Duxton
Overeasy
Flor Patisserie
Cat & The Fiddle
Harry's
The Singapore Straits Wine Company - UE Square
GO LOCO by Lucha Loco
Alter Ego by A Poke Theory
Butterknife Folk
Tess Bar & Kitchen
Cajun on Wheels (C.O.W) - Plaza Singapura
Barossa
Molly Roffey's Irish Pub
Jack's Place
Wine Connection Bistro
Rosso Vino
Red Tail
Harry's